# Only some routes work on Node express

Tags: node.js, express, dreamhost

I've been developing a website for a while now locally. Using Ubuntu, nodejs and express. I recently moved it to my VPS on Dreamhost and it has some strange behavior. Everything worked fine on my localhost but on the VPS only some routes work. By this I mean if I go to `mydomain.com` then I get the website. Then if I go to `mydomain.com/panel` it loads, however, it is supposed to check for a user session but doesn't, it just sends them to the panel. Then if I try to go to `mydomain.com/contact` or any other route on my website, it just won't load. I get a 500 error.

This is my `panel` route, which is found in `routes/panel.js`

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var sess = req.session;
  if(sess.user) res.status(200).sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../public/panel.html'));
  else res.status(200).sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../public/admin.html'));
});
```

This is my `contact` route, which is found in `routes/contact.js`

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send("Hello");
});
```

In `app.js` I add both of these routes like this,

```
app.use('/contact', contact);
app.use('/panel', panel);
```

This all works on my localhost. All of the correct modules are present. For some reason it is not working on the Dreamhost VPS.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles across this while working with Dreamhost VPS. The issue I was having is I forgot to set up a proxy server and run nodejs on the correct port. Somehow Dreamhost was rendering the files in my public folder but wasn't actually using nodejs to do it. It was simply resolved by creating a proxy server to port 8000 and then running nodejs on port 8000.

Comment: Hi! How might one go about doing this?

Comment: @Cullub I did this 4 years ago, so I can not give you an answer as I do not remember. However, since my time as a software engineer, I would suggest moving away from DreamHost and focus more on a cloud service like AWS, Azure, or Google Cloud.